# Given an invertible matrix $A$, can we study the signs of $A^{-1}$ 's without actually computing it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix. I am interested in the general problem of studying the structure of $A^{-1}$ without actually performing the inversion: especially, I am interested in the sign of $A^{-1}$'s entries.
In particular I would like to know if there exist sufficient (and necessary) conditions on $A$ so that:
$$A^{-1}\quad \text{has non-negative diagonal elements and non-positive off-diagonal elements}$$
(in other terms, it's a $Z$-matrix with non-negative diagonal elements, I don't know a specific name, but for example $M$-matrices show this property, as pointed out in the comments ).

As an example, when $A$ is $2\times 2$, i.e.
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\
                   a_{21} & a_{22}
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
we have
$$A^{-1}= \frac{1}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}} 
\begin{bmatrix} a_{22} & -a_{12} \\
                   -a_{21} & a_{11}
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
so that the conditions I am searching are
$$a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22}\geq (\leq) 0$$
together with the invertibility condition $$a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}>(<)0$$
I think also the $3\times 3$ case can be worked out similarly.

But what about the general $n\times n$ case ?

Comment: It seems you are working with real numbers? For complex matrices, this doesn't make sense, or for entries in a finite field. For $n\ge 3$ the conditions are already complicated, I think. Can you state the result you have found for $n=3$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, the matrix takes real entries. I took it for granted, I will update the question. I still have to work out the n=3 case, mine was just wishful thinking!

Comment: This seems very relevant: https://nhigham.com/2021/03/16/what-is-an-m-matrix/

Comment: Here's just my initial thought for this problem. One can compute the entries of $A^{-1}$ purely in terms of determinants of sub-matrices of $A$. The sign of a determinant has a geometric meaning, so if you have a geometric understanding of these sub-matrices then you would know the signs of the entries of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @CarlChristian thanks, indeed a sufficient condition for the problem above would be that A is the inverse of an M-matrix. The problem is that I did not found any explicit characterization of this class (only characterizations involving infinite numbers of checks)

Comment: @Dave thanks! Sadly my matrix is basically the difference of two Jacobians, so I wouldn't know how to work geometrically... The problem is one of comparative statics

Comment: The condition for invertibility of a 2-dimensional matrix is $\text{det}(A) = a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21} \ne 0$. $A$ will still be invertible when the determinant is negative. So the 2-condition is actually $\text{det}(A), a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{21}, a_{22}$ are all the same sign (where $0$ can be intepreted as having either sign).

Comment: @PaulSinclair you are right, in my application it will be positive, but here I was indeed writing in general

Comment: Unfortunately, in higher dimensions, the direct formulas for the elements of the inverse get more complicated. They can be found by [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Analytic_solution) which is efficient for 3x3 and smaller matrices, but quickly becomes highly inefficient.  Those easy 2d rules do not give rise to easy higher-dimensional rules.